# link_to_unless_current assign class to disabled (current) link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Anyone know if you can assign a tag and class to the disabled or current link? The example below only displays as plain text in the browser for the current link.

I have a bit of rails code displaying a list of buttons for each design in the database.

```
<% @id_cards.each do |id| %>
 <%= link_to_unless_current id.design_type, id_card_design_path(id.id), :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

The active links are assigned the correct class and display as buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link_to_unless_current` accepts a block which can be used to override the default behavior.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current

```
<%=
  link_to_unless_current("Comment", { :controller => "comments", :action => "new" }) do
    link_to("Go back", { :controller => "posts", :action => "index" })
  end
%>
```

In the example above it would yield the 'Go back' link if the current page was the 'new comment' page.

Comment: Thank you, I did read this info on the API site. This solution seems a bit manual and not what I am looking for. I would like to still have the option to build the link automatically from the `<% @id_cards.each do |id| %>` any additional tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

@James gave proper answer its just you are too young to take it right :)

```
<% @id_cards.each do |id| %>
 <%=
 link_to_unless_current(id.design_type, id_card_design_path(id.id), :class => 'btn') do
  content_tag(:p, id.design_type, :class => :some_class
 end
 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @James response. Your example works great.